# Matrix multiplication and differentiation

Tags: matrix-calculus

I am very confused reading all those symbols I do not understand, I am just trying to find partial derivative when two matrices are multiplied.

For an example, suppose that $A$ is a $3\times 4$ matrix and that $B$ is a $4\times 2$.

After I do multiplication $f(A,B) = AB$, I get a matrix $3\times 2$ matrix $C$.

Now my question is, if I try to find the partial derivative of $f(A,B)$ with respect to $B$, do I use the same rule as with scalars? I guess not, correct, so would anyone be so nice and tell to me a simple person how I could solve this. Please do not write in equations, because I can not read them! I understand mathematics only from intuition.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand what you are asking.  What is $f$?  What is $F$?  How are you defining the derivative of a function with respect to a matrix?  Where are you seeing this notation?

Comment: F is f = function. f(A,B) = A dot B Hopefully you understand me know:)

Comment: So $f$ is just multiplication of the two functions?  And $F$ is the same thing?  Why have you used different symbols for them, then?  Also, what about the rest of my questions?

Comment: like I said... I can not read symbols. I am sorry. I don't understand what you mean, but I guess, if we have partial derivatives with ordinary numbers, we must have it with matrixes as well, right?

Comment: @XanderHenderson And when we try to find partial derivatives with scalars... like x,y,z, we have rules..  is there something with matrixes... thanks

Comment: Symbols are the language of mathematics.  If you can't understand the basic notation, then I highly doubt that you are going to make any progress on the question that you are asking.  As was said in response to [another question you asked on the same topic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2696421/paradox-of-matrix-derivative), this is "Utterly incomprehensible".

Comment: ahh... I understand math in full depth, I just can't read the symbols...ah never mind. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Short solution based on the most elementary definitions of the subject (but nothing "full depth", sorry about that... or not): let $g(B)=f(A,B)$, then $g(B+tH)=A(B+tH)=AB+tAH=g(B)+tAH$ hence $\langle\nabla g(B),H\rangle=AH$, which some would shorten into $\frac{\partial g(B)}{\partial B}=A$, I guess.

Comment: @Did Thanks my friend :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each entry of the $3 \times 2$ matrix $C$ is a function of the entries of $B$, so we can take the partial derivative with respect to each entry of $B$.

Since $c_{ij} = a_{i1} b_{1j} + a_{i2} b_{2j} + a_{i3} b_{3j} + a_{i4} b_{4j}$, one could write $\frac{\partial c_{ij}}{\partial b_{kj}} = a_{ik}$ and $\frac{\partial c_{ij}}{\partial b_{k\ell}} = 0$ for $\ell \ne j$. Then you can somehow arrange this into a $3 \times 2 \times 4 \times 2$ array of partial derivatives and call this the "partial derivative of $f$ with respect to $B$."